# touchpad sometimes doesn't respond

Tags: touchpad, vaio

Sometimes the pointer stop move while my finger is moving over the touchpad and I have to try several times. I did not have the issue in the past (or at least very rare), but since a few weeks, the issue become very annoying.
I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 over sony vaio laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be a expert, BUT I did have this issue once upon a time and quickly solved it with these solutions. Problem could be hardware or software related, which cause then lags- unresponsiveness.

- Look at your touch pad, is it greasy, dirty? It could be merely a dirty touchpad, which in turn the pad doesn't register movement from your fingers
  Solution: Give it a good old scrub! (This applies to mouses, clean your mouse and surface underneath).
- Could it be too much strain on your laptop? 
  Solution: Try closing down application, windows, EVERYTHING in your desktop environment. Free sum spaceeee, give your cpu, memory, gpu some room to breath.
- Could be a overworked and tired laptop? 
  Step 1: COMPLETELY shutdown that machine of yours, dont charge it, leave it AlONE.
  Step 2: Put your laptop in a cool environment (not your fridge).
  Step 3: Leave it for more than 4-6 hours.
  Step 4: Go outside and kick a ball or somthing
  Step 5: Wait for it to cool down
- Could it be that your laptop has a completely full hard drive? Spring clean that hard drive. Clean it up, make room, your pc will thank you for that.
  Solution: Your laptop has room to write more imformation into that hard drive, whichh in turn happy laptop :).
- This is last resort, But I see you posted your using Ubuntu version 15.10, since this isn't LTS (Long Term Support) could be buggy? I suggest that you perform a fresh install of Linux Ubuntu 15.10 OR roll back over to Ubuntu 14.04 (More Stable Version). Oh also doing a fresh install is the ultimate solution for software wise.
- Could be a virus? Viruses can have a huge performance slowdown
  Solution: Identify virus and eliminate problem OR performing a full system wipe and fresh install of operating system- ONLY FOR DIRE SITUATIONS!!!!!!

So these are some of my methods of solving these problems im sure there are hundreds more solutions out on the interwebs my main recommendation is rolling back to Ubuntu 14.04 which means a full reinstall of the operating system, this method solved my problem with the trackpad.
How do you like them apples? Pls feel free to ask any questions relating to this problem! ;)

Comment: Thx for all information you provided. It seems to  be it is hardware issue.